# Related to genre and category

Tags: categories

I am trying to add movie from IDBM by using IDBM importer plugin, the imported movie is going to genre only. I am unable to categories these movie according to Hollywood and Bollywood but it is showing only in genre option.
How to fix it????

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very understandable.... I've never used this plugin, like most people here.  It's hard for us to help you, I think your question is too specific and you should contact the author of the plugin. If you find the solution to your problem, don't hesitate to publish it here in response, it may be useful to someone else.